# Adding Custom Error Page To Admin Area In MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-error-pages, custom-error-handling

In my web site, there are two sections, 
 1. Pages that can be accessed by any user(public users).
 2. Admin area which is accessed by authenticated users.


To show 404 error for the public users, I have created custom page and added the following section to the root web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound"/>
 </customErrors>
```

To show custom 404 error for admin area, I have created a custom page inside the admin area views and added the following section to the web.config in the admin area folder.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="~/Admin/AdminError/AdminError" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
```

When I tried to create a 404 error(by typing an invalid admin url) the application shows the 404 page in the root folder.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Add an Area to your application.  Right-click your project and click Add...Area.  Call it Admin.  Actually you just set it in your main web.config.

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/500.html">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.html" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500.html" />
</customErrors>
</system.web>

<location path="MyArea1">
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Areas/MyArea1/500.html">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Areas/MyArea1/404.html" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Areas/MyArea1/500.html" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Then handle Application_Error in Global.asax.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string area = Request.FilePath.Split('/')[1];
        if (area.Equals("AreaName"))
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            Response.Clear();
            HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

            switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
            {
                case 404:
                    Server.Transfer("~/Areas/AreaName/404.html");
                    break;
                case 500:
                default:
                    Server.Transfer("~/Areas/AreaName/500.html");
                    break;
            }
            Server.ClearError();
        }
    }
```

Comment: in the above, the second piece of code, is what I added in the "admin" area web.config. still when I tried to generate a 404 error, my application shows the custom error page in the root folder, not the "admin" area custom error page.